# Mixpanel Ruby API equivalent to mixpanel.register from JavaScript API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, analytics, mixpanel

I am using Mixpanel's JavaScript and Ruby API's in my application. The [JavaScript API](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/javascript) offers the `register` method; this allows you set super properties so that each time you track an event it automatically records those properties as well, so that you don't have to specify the same properties with every event.

The [Ruby API](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/ruby) doesn't appear to offer anything like this.

The majority of my tracking is using the Ruby API, and each time I track something I'm recording the same properties: `user_type` (admin, basic user, etc.), and `user_name`.

Is there any way that I can set super properties when recording events in Ruby like I can with the JavaScript API, so that each time I track something, these properties are automatically recorded?

Answer (score 0):

**Use**

> mixpanel.register(<%= super_props.to_json.html_safe %>)

- super_props is the variable which stores super properties.